# yql to pull information on all stocks price

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I am building program to find out top 10(N) stocks based on open/close price change but so far I only found that i have to provide symbol to pull stock info. Is there a more generic yql to pull info about all stocks?

Comment: Hi @rupal, which programming language are you using ? I built a python library a couple years ago which might be help [mYQL](https://github.com/josuebrunel/myql.git)

Comment: I'll check your library.  Thanks. I'm looking for rest api which can give me list of stocks ticker symbols based on stock exchange which I can use at yql to pull further information.